# Determine the existence of a path between relations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, graph, set

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4 database storing organization and person tables.
There is an organization_person table linking organizations to people.
Organizations have multiple people, and people may belong to more than one
organization.

I want to be able to efficiently answer the query: for a given
organization X, does there exist a path between that organization, through
at most one person, to any organization in set S, the set of organizations
having a certain boolean field set to true?

Only two-hop connections through people need be found.
Finding X -- Person -- Y -- Person -- s isn't necessary.

The set S has about 10,000 entries. Most organizations aren't in S.
This is for online query purposes, not offline analytics or other batch processing. Updates to S are rarer; about 150 additions per day, with a few removals.

I'm willing to use of advanced features or extensions of PostgreSQL, or
other database technologies if they're simply far more suited to the task.
I only need to know whether such a path exists, not its members. I'm
willing to do this with a certain amount of denormalisation in PostgreSQL,
but I'm not sure how to integrate changes, such as changes to the
membership of S, in a sane and efficient
manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a person who is in organization X and an organization in S.  This can be expressed as a SQL query:

```
select 1
from s join
     organization_person op
     on op.organzation_id = s.organization_id join
     organization_person opx
     on opx.organization_id = 'x' and
        opx.person_id = op.person_id
limit 1;
```

This will benefit from indexes on `organization_person(organization_id, person_id)` and `organization_person(person_id, organization_id)`.